# Are horses slower with armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently I was watching a Minecraft stream and it looked like horses with armor where slower than the ones without armor. Is this a game mechanic or are some horses just faster than the others?

Comment: Some horses are faster than others, but I'm not sure if armour has any effect on speed.

Comment: Fantastic feature idea.

Comment: @Mutantoe It would definitely make sense :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In minecraft armour does not affect the player or a mob's speed, the diffrence in speed is because of the random NBT tag the horse has for the speed.

> [Compared to the player's walking speed, the maximum speed ranges from merely 25% faster to 337.5% times faster.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse#Health.2C_Jump_Height.2C_Speed)

All nbt values can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format) (gamepedia)

Answer (score 3):

I have played many hours of Minecraft and I have never noticed my horse go slower. So if it does, it is so minuscule that the armor would be worth it.

Also Google your question; there are several videos testing this, including a Mythbusting episode by Xisumavoid:

The armor test starts at 1:20.